# Issue with MySql Unique key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here are my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE  users_registration 
(user_id int4  NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
request_id int4  NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
status bpchar  NOT NULL, 
session_id varchar(100)  NOT NULL, 
attempts int4, 
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, request_id));
```

In one place it is taking `request_id=1` everytime when new  record creating but another new MYSQL Database i am getting thi exception

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'request_id'
```

Can anyone tell what is the issue using Hibernate in my application.

[image]

Comment: You are using request_id as unique that's why getting this error

Comment: Its working fine with another database i just import table and now getting issue

Comment: Why do you have a `Unique` key on `request_id` when you are knowingly inserting the same value into it?

Comment: ADDED OLD DB SCREEN SHOT